# Determinant value always in field of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a hard time finding a clear answer on this, but it might be because vector spaces is new to me.

If I have matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, are they then both part of some vector space $U\subset V$ where $(V,+,*)$ is some $\mathbb{F}$ vector space? And is this why the determinant of $A,B$ both are in $\mathbb{F}$?

Sorry if this is too vague a question.

Comment: You are taking the determinant of a matrix which is over a field $\mathbb{F} $, so obviously by the formula of the determinant and by the close property under addition and multIplication of a  field, it should lie in $\mathbb{F} $

Answer (score 1):

All of the square matrices of a fixed size over a field (written $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{F})$) form a vector space, where vector addition is matrix addition, and vector scaling is scaling every entry of the matrix. However, this isn't really the reason that the determinant of $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{F})$ lies in $\mathbb{F}$. The simplest reason that the determinant lies in $\mathbb{F}$ is that there are formulas for the determinant which only depend on the entries of $A$, for example repeatedly expanding along rows or columns.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it possible to explain that $det(AB)\in\mathbb{F}$ as the determinant is computed through vector addition and vector scaling or is that gibberish?

Comment: @bubububub: it's not quite gibberish, but what do you mean by "computed through vector addition and vector scaling"? Anything that comes out of those two operations is a vector, so how exactly would you get the determinant?